# iPad does not see external stylesheet

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ipad

Days of Internet research and worsening frustration lead me here. I cannot figure this out. Perhaps a wiser person can help.

Using web developer tools, every site page displays fine in every tested browser. However, when I check on an actual iPad and iPhone, no page displays correctly. What's wrong is that none of the CSS in style.css is executing on the iPad / iPhone.

I am using bootstrap, which it sees, but it does not see my style sheet (css/style.css). I have tested too many things to list, including absolute versus relative URLs, and rearranging the link tags in the header.

I tested inline and head-embedded styles and both work. But this is unacceptable to me.

I removed all code from the footer, leaving one div with a class from the external stylesheet, and that did not work. The iPad is blind to it.

I cannot debug the iPad from the iPad (I know Safari has instructions for this), but I have other bootstrap sites I coded that work fine and comparing them I cannot see what I am doing differently now.

I re-booted my iPad many times in case it was a cache issue.

I left out code in this question because I do not know what code to show. I can provide code or URLs or anything else if that helps. The pages are published.

I appreciate any assistance.  Thank you.

Comment: When you hook your iPad up to your Mac and observe the dev tools in Safari for it, what HTTP status code are you getting in response for that resource?

Comment: Without seeing your site/code, there's really not a lot we can help with.

Comment: Could you be missing the meta tag <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> ?

Comment: @Quantastical I have not hooked it up to

Comment: @Satbir  Safari<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: David, Here's the URL where I'm building it:  http://www.bizkast.com/armalaser

Comment: Looks fine at my end, what is missing on your iPad?

Comment: Are you viewing it on an iPad?  My iPad and iPhone and mobiletest.me all display the same thing, namely, the site without the styles in css/styles.css.

Comment: The most blaring is the header and footer, includes files, but the missing styles extends to the main content as well. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: On mobiletest.me from my desktop, the site displays perfectly. Yet, on my iPad and my wife's iPhone it does not. And also it does not display properly on mobiletest.me when I access mobiletest.me on my iPad.

Comment: Well, it maybe that your html/css is malformed, and that browsers will correct them and continue parsing, while mobile devices give up. [See here](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bizkast.com%2Farmalaser%2Fcss%2Fstyle.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en) and [here](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bizkast.com%2Farmalaser%2F)

Comment: @SatbirKira This is helpful!  I will examine this and report back! I already fixed item #1.

Comment: @JimB814 Starting to look good on my ipad. Nice work!

Comment: @SatbirKira I was commenting out lines with // instead of /* code */.  After repairing this, the site displays perfectly on my iPad.  This is wonderful!  You are right in saying that browsers compensate for "wrong" code with workarounds unique to each browser. Although this appears helpful, I prefer the benefits afforded by forcing adherence to the strictest standards.

Comment: @JimB814 You should use notepadd++ or some other kind of text editor with syntax highlighting, it makes it very easy to spot syntax errors so you avoid these kinds of headaches. I sometimes wish I could use chrome dev  tools to run in strict parse mode but then again, it's my job to make sure my code is valid, not the browsers.

Comment: @SatbirKira Thanks for your help and advice.